# Pop up showing the same page in liferay

Tags: liferay

I have a portlet in which there is a pop up .The content of the popup does not change but instead shows the same page from where it is clicked.When i click the notify button the popup shows but with the content of view.jsp.

**All the code is present in view.jsp**

```
 <%@page import="com.mvantage.contract.model.Contract"%>
 <%@ include file="/init.jsp" %>


 <portlet:defineObjects />

 <%

 PortletURL actionURL1=renderResponse.createActionURL();
 actionURL1.setParameter(ActionRequest.ACTION_NAME,"navigateDashboard");
 ArrayList<Contract> contractParameterList=    (ArrayList<Contract>)renderRequest.getAttribute("contract");%>



   <portlet:renderURL var="contractURL" windowState="<%=  LiferayWindowState.POP_UP.toString()%>">
   <portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/html/popup.jsp" />
   </portlet:renderURL>



  <script type="text/javascript">
   alert("Inside new popup");
    function showPopup() {
      AUI().use('aui-dialog', 'aui-io', 'event', 'event-custom', function(A) {

    var dialog = new A.Dialog({
        title: 'Pop Up',
        centered: true,
        draggable: true,
        modal: true,
        width: 500,
       height: 500,
        }).plug(A.Plugin.IO, {uri: '<%= contractURL %>'}).render();

        dialog.show();

  });
}
```

```
 <div id="container">

  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example4">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>a</th>
            <th>b/th>
            <th>c</th>
            <th>d</th>
            <th>e</th>
            <th>f</th>
            <th>g</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <%for(int i=0; i<contractParameterList.size(); i++ ){
            Contract contractParameter = new Contract();
            contractParameter = (Contract)contractParameterList.get(i);
        %>
            <tr class="odd gradeX">

            <td><%=contractParameter.getAssetName()%></td>
            <%actionURL1.setParameter("assetId",contractParameter.getAssetID());%>
            <td><a href="<%=actionURL1.toString()%>"><%=contractParameter.getAssetID()%></a></td>
            <td><%=contractParameter.getCustomerName()%></td>
            <td><%=contractParameter.getLocation()%></td>
            <td><%=contractParameter.getRiskType()%></td>
            <td><%=contractParameter.getContractNotificationTrigger()%></td>
            <td><input class="notify" type="button" value="Notify" onclick="showPopup('<%=contractURL.toString()%>')"></td></tr> <%} %></tbody></table> <div style="clear:both;"></div></div>
```

Comment: "/html/popup.jsp" check your location. provide your project structure

Comment: The location is fine .The file is located at "/abc-portlet/docroot/html/popup.jsp".

Answer (score 0):

The way you are using the A.Dialog it's not the best for me.

Try to use this way: http://alloyui.com/versions/1.7.x/examples/dialog/real-world/

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can try below simplified code :

```
<aui:button value="Pop Up" icon="av-icon" iconAlign="left"
                    type="button" onClick="displayPopUp()" cssClass="notify" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    function displayPopUp(){
        Liferay.Util.openWindow({dialog: {width: 500,height: 500,destroyOnHide: true}, title: 'Pop Up', uri: '<%=contractURL%>
    '
        });
    }
</script>
```